# Como hacer una variante de Strategy con genericos

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un mapeo entre dos clases y utilizo strategy:

```
    public interface IMapeo<T, A>
    {
        List<A> Obtener(List<T> objectData);
    }

    public class Mapeo<T, A>
    {
        private IMapeo<T, A> _strategy;

        public IMapeo<T, A> Strategy {
            set => _strategy = value;
        }
        
        public Mapeo(IMapeo<T,A> strategy)
        {
            _strategy = strategy;
        }

        public List<A> Map(List<T> objectData)
            => _strategy.Obtener(objectData);
    }
```

Implemento la interfaz con este mapeo:

```
public class FacturaMapper : IMapeo<FacturaDataDTO, Factura>
{

    public List<Factura> Obtener(List<FacturaDataDTO> objectData)
    {
        // Mapeo con LinQ
    }
}
```

Para poder utilizar este mapeo, lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
var Mapper = new Mapeo<FacturaDataDTO, Factura>(new FacturaMapper());
var factura = Mapper.Map(facturaData).FirstOrDefault();
```

Ahora va mi duda. Lo que yo quiero lograr es que se pueda hacer el mapeo, con algo parecido a este codigo:

```
var factura = new Mapeo<FacturaDataDTO, Factura>(facturaData);
```

y que la variable 'factura' sea una lista de la entidad factura. ¿Habra alguna forma de poder lograrlo?

Comment: Porque no usas automapper? ya hace todo el trabajo por ti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo mucho tu lógica, yo supongo que siempre necesitaras pasar el "new FacturaMapper()" tambien no solo "facturaData". De todas maneras te muestro 2 ejemplo de cómo realizarlo, tu deberás afinarlos

**1) Heredar de List**

```
public class Mapeo<T, A> : List<A>
{
    private IMapeo<T, A> _strategy;

    public IMapeo<T, A> Strategy
    {
        set => _strategy = value;
    }

    public Mapeo(IMapeo<T, A> strategy, List<T> objectData)
    {
        _strategy = strategy;
        foreach(var item in Map(objectData))
        {
            this.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public List<A> Map(List<T> objectData)
        => _strategy.Obtener(objectData);
}
```

```
var factura = new Mapeo<FacturaDataDTO, Factura>(new FacturaMapper(),facturaData);
```

factura será del tipo Mapeo, pero también una lista. Podrás iterarla con for/foreach

**2) Usando conversiones implícitas**

```
public class Mapeo<T, A>
{
    private IMapeo<T, A> _strategy;
    private List<T> objectData { get; set; }

    public IMapeo<T, A> Strategy
    {
        set => _strategy = value;
    }

    public Mapeo(IMapeo<T, A> strategy, List<T> objectData)
    {
        _strategy = strategy;
        this.objectData = objectData;
    }

    public List<A> Map()
        => _strategy.Obtener(objectData);

        
    public static implicit operator List<A>(Mapeo<T, A> mapeo) =>  mapeo.Map();

}
```

```
List<Factura> factura = new Mapeo<FacturaDataDTO, Factura>(new FacturaMapper(),facturaData);
```

*NdA: Todo esto de los Mapper y los DTO provocan tener 2 o 3 clases adicionales por cada entidad. Lo cual genera una gran cantidad de clases que se confunden por su nombre, lo que lleva inevitablemente al código spaguetti y además presentan una difícil depuración ya que realizan conversiones de forma automáticas. En mi experiencia existen muchos patrones (DTO, DDD, Repository) que vienen de otros lenguajes (JAVA especialmente) y que no aplican directamente en .NET, porque este último cuenta con sus propios patrones que ya están integrados y que muchas veces son análogos (pero no iguales) a otros patrones*